# IE 8 + cache clearing... IE8 will not load newer versions of a .jpg file

Tags: internet-explorer-8, browser-cache

I have put

```
<meta http-equiv="Refresh" content="120"><!-- Should update every 120 seconds-->
<meta http-equiv="cache-control" content="no-cache"><!-- prevent caching -->
<meta http-equiv="expires" content="0"><!-- prevent caching -->
```

in the top of my code; however, IE 8 will not load a new version of a .jpg file each time it refreshes at the end of the period.

I have picked up from this forum that

Press F12. Click Cache -> Always Refresh from Server

solves the problem for me, but restarting the browser restores the "Always Refresh from Server" status to not selected.

How do I make this selection permenant (so I do not have to select this every time I load the browser?)

Comment: Looks like your code got cleared out by the sanitiser.  Put it on its own lines with four spaces at the beginning of the line.  Does Ctrl-F5 bring up the new version of the jpg?